# MVC and WebApi controllers have different parsing behavior

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I recently added a webapi controller alongside my existing MVC controllers in an asp.net project. I did this to allow features, like Swashbuckle, which were not available with regular MVC API controllers.

However, I have noticed that the WebApi controllers do not parse objects in a list the same way that the MVC controllers did.

This pattern works for MVC controllers to submit form data with AJAX.

```html
<body>
    <form action="cart/additems" method="post" id="add-form">
        <input type="hidden" name="items[0].Id" value="de63da9b-f4c8-4727-9ef8-0bae8a538503" />
        <input type="hidden" name="items[0].Quantity" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="items[1].Id" value="de63da9b-f4c8-4727-9ef8-0bae8a538503" />
        <input type="hidden" name="items[1].Quantity" value="1" />
        <button type="submit" class="button">ADD</a>
    </form>
    <a href="#" id="link-click">click me</a>
</body>

<script>
    $('#link-click').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/cart/additems',
            type: 'post',
            data: $('#add-form').serialize(),
            success: function () { }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the corresponding MVC Controller Method

```cs
public ActionResult AddItems(List<OrderItem> items)
{
    ...
}
```

When the MVC controller is used, the `List<OrderItem> items` parameter is correctly populated. However, when I switch to WebApi with the same method signature, `items` is not correctly populated. I've tried many things, like adding the `[FromUri]` and `[FromBody]` attributes and changing from `post` to `get`.

The WebApi method does work when a raw javascript data object is sent as the data parameter in the ajax call. So, the only thing I can currently think to do is write a piece of code that takes the `$('form').serialize()` or `$('form').serializeObject()` jQuery results and makes a javascript array out of them. However, it seems like this should be a solved problem already.

Does anyone know how I might modify the WebApi controller so it accepts query string list annotation the same way the MVC controller did?

Comment: can you check which Newtonsoft DLL version you are using in both projects

Comment: @satsvelke, both controllers are in the same project. They use Newtonsoft Json 10.0.3